# How to use UV maps for stickers?

Tags: modeling, uv

I want to know how to place colourful images on a surface using uv. I want to make such lego heads with different colourful faces/expressions. (The images are transparent pngs, also No shrinkwrap plz)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a material that mixes a yellow *Principled BSDF* with an *Image Texture* that has your faces PNG loaded:

[image]

Unwrap the object, scale down the UVs and put them over a transparent part of your image, then unwrap the front faces only and put them over one of the expressions:

[image]

Then for each object, use the exact same materials except you move the UV:

[image]

Comment: Man! This is perfect! Why is this method not available anywhere on YouTube? All there is is the use of Shrinkwrap modifier. WOW Thanks man!

Comment: It is available on YouTube, but it's a pretty old tutorial (Blender 2.7). This is the relevant video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY

Comment: Also, If you add another principled bsdf to the color socket of the UV texture then you can adjust the gloss of the UV texture.

Comment: of course you can also use one unique material, only move the front faces, and put the rest of the unwrapped UVs over a transparent part of the image

Comment: OK I've simplified my answer